# Github pushing to a private repo, not found error

Tags: git, github

I can't exactly find the answer to my issue, or I'm just missing something.

I created an empty private repo on GitHub. I have an existing Git project on my local machine.

I would like to push the local Git project to the existing private repo, but receiving the "Repository not found" error.

Used the following commands provided by GitHub:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/url.git
git push -u origin master
```

If I use the Github GUI application, which lets me login, I can push an existing local Git project to my private Github repo no problem.

I would prefer to push from the Terminal however.

Comment: This is incredibly vague. At least show some of the commands that you ran, especially the clone command.

Comment: Try with source tree its best. If your command are not strong

Comment: Try `git show remote <your github remote>` and see if it prompts for any authentication. is it over https or ssh?

Comment: I used the commands GitHub lists out "git remote add origin..." and "git push -u origin master" nothing else. I was never prompted for a username or password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the issue. I had a different GitHub account saved in my Keychain. When trying to push to origin, I wasn't prompted for a new username/password, because it kept trying to use whatever was saved in my Keychain.

Here are instructions on fixing that: https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/

Also, if you use 2 Step Authentication, you will need to create an Personal Access Token and use that instead of your GitHub password. Instructions on creating a token are here: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/